# Run Java executable without installing JRE?

Tags: deployment, java, executable-jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running java without installing jre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371535/running-java-without-installing-jre)

I am working on a Java application. I created an executable .jar file of my application. It works fine on my machine. Now, I want to deploy it over the client machines which don't have JRE locally.

- Is there any way to run my executable jar file without installing JRE locally?
- Alternately: What minimum files are required from the JRE folder so I can pack them with my installation package?

Suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: *"I want to deploy it"*  How do you intend to deliver it?  The web?  Disk? [IPoAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) (Carrier pigeon)?  -- Does the app. have a GUI?  I suspect there are much better answers than those already offered, but the devil is in the details of the answers to those 2 questions.

Comment: No, the app has no GUI. It's a console application. I want to deploy as a jar (may be in a disk).

Answer (score 1):

> What minimum files are required from the jre or jdk folder so I can
>   pack them with my installation package??

You can pack a jre with your runnable .jar with software like [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to pack the `jre.jar` with your application (you can of course even include it in your char). Some of the jar>executable tools already provide this option (for instance [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) as user1444702 already mentioned).