# How to run .exe file converted from .jar file using Launch4J tool without Jre

Tags: exe, java, executable-jar, launch4j

I converted my jar file into .exe using Launch4J. Now as per my need I have to run this exe file on system with no JRE installed. Is it possible to run .exe file converted from jar file without JRE or is there any way to embed JRE with the .exe file?

Comment: For a system without its own JRE, you can bundle JRE together with your program in its own program installed directory using a setup installer. Set your Launch4J of your program to refer its JRE path to the location of your JRE copy. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664858/how-can-you-package-an-executable-jar-with-a-portable-jre?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

the exe is just a facility to run the program on windows, it is also needed the JRE.

[]'s

Comment: thank you Sir for ur response...I just wanted to know if there is a facility already present on windows to run java applications without installing jre..

Comment: @Ram The EXE file created by Launch4J is just a wrapper to `javaw.exe` found in JRE. Therefore, it still needs the class-path to the JRE installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need JRE for running a .exe file.But if you create a .exe file from a jar file, you should have JAVA in your system or in any other PC you want to run the .exe file. So JRE comes with the JAVA when installed(only basic thing). I think you can include JRE by using launch4j. I used it long back ago. But I won't personally recommend it. I always use Jar2EXE for converting the jar file to an .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

1. it's not possible to run the exe without JRE (since the exe is just wrapper of jar)
2. I would suggest you to use a setup tool to create an Installer. It's the easiest way. Launch4j is not capable of putting JRE into exe, so you would have to send 2 parts (exe + JRE). However if you create an Installer, you'll have just 1 exe file where you have packaged everything. I'd recommend Inno Setup Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know with Launch4J.

But you can do it with NetBeans and a couple of tools. The result is a standalone installer that packages everything you need (included java files), so your software can run without installing JRE. But in the end it does need JRE to run, only that everything is included, and it's totally portable.
[here is this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664858/how-can-you-package-an-executable-jar-with-a-portable-jre/58196153#58196153)