# how to make an executable jar which includes a java and a jar file

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, executable-jar

I have a java file simpleMail.java and a jar file java-mail-1.4.jar (which is used in simpleMail.java). What I want to do is make an executable jar file out of these files and run on cmd.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Are u using intellij idea?

Comment: @SteelToe no just notepad. i need to run it on cmd

Comment: If u would use intellij j, they have an option to generate a jar with all dependencies

Comment: @JimGarrison i'll be glad if you'll help me out for an answer.

Comment: @AnujVictor google around for "Java uberjar" and rephrase your question.  What have you tried?

Comment: @SteelToe so there isn't any way without it?

Comment: I believe u need a fat jar. Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089189/how-to-make-a-fat-jar-of-a-maven-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you package an executable jar with a portable JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664858/how-can-you-package-an-executable-jar-with-a-portable-jre)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. create manifest.txt file as
Main-Class: Main-Class-Name

Step2. compile all classes.

Step 3. run JDK's jar.exe utility like:

jar cvfm JarName.jar manifest.txt *.class
cvfm is create a jar; show verbose output; specify the output jar file name; specify the manifest file name. (*.class means all class files in the current directory.)

Step 4. specify jar dependency on classpath.

For detail refer http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: how to specify jar dependency in classpath.

Comment: java -cp 'MyProgram.jar:libs/*' MainClass put jar in lib folder.